# Docker newbie setup troubles

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm a beginner with Docker, and attempting to setup a little dev environment to replicate a system in production.

### Using

- Docker-Toolbox (windows)
- Docker-Compose

#### Requirements

These are required to match the production server

- Apache 2.2
- PHP 5.3
- MySQL 5.1
- PhpMyAdmin

I'm setting this up using CentOS:6

#### docker-compose.yml

```
web:
    container_name: web
    build: .
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    volumes:
        - ./www/:/var/www/html
    links:
        - mysql:mysql
mysql:
    container_name: db
    image: mtirsel/mysql-5.1
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
        - ./db/:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:6

RUN rpm -iUvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
RUN yum -y update && yum -y install httpd php php-mysql php-mysqli phpmyadmin && yum clean all

RUN sed -i 's/short_open_tag = Off/short_open_tag = On/g' /etc/php.ini

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

I've tried a bunch of different setups and configs (from online) but nothing is working.  Do I have this setup correctly?  I'd like to have two containers, one for the web (apache, php, phpmyadmin, website content) and the other linked (mysql).  MySQL has a mounted volume, as does the web.

Mysql doesn't always connect or stay up, nor does the phpMyAdmin. I've even changed the `phpMyAdmin.conf` to allow everything, plus changing the `config.inc.php` setting the host to `127.0.0.1` and `AllowNoPassword` to TRUE

How can I properly set this up via Docker Compose?

Comment: What kind of error is stopping the "db" container when you run "docker-compose up" ?

Comment: Yes, I think we'll need the error messages and/or the contents of any config files that point at the database to really debug this. Generally it looks correct from what you've provided.

Comment: quite late to ask, but are you done with this thing?